# List to Notepad in Blender

Tags: python, list, blender, bpy

```
import bpy

f = open("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/CODING.txt", 'w')

for i in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    
    result = print(i.name.split(".")[1])
    result = str(result)
    f.write(result)

f.close()
```

I selected 5 objects in Blender and ran the script.

The names of the objects are cube.001 ~ cube.005

What I want is to write 001 to 005 in notepad.

However, "None" was written on the notepad (5 times)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` returns `None`. Just use `result = i.name.split(".")[1]` instead. And no need to convert it to string afterward. So this would suffice:

```
import bpy

with open("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/CODING.txt", 'w') as f:
    for i in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        f.write(i.name.split(".")[1])
```

Note that if you use context manager for opening a file (`with` statement) you don't need to close it manualy.